Does JPA call a stored procedure in the same transaction?
I have a stored procedure that does not handle transactions (no commit, rollback) and I call it from a method like this:
@Transactional
void work(Long id) {
   var entity = (id == null) ? create() || fetch(id);
   process(entity);
   repository.callProcedure(id);
} 

This code works fine for existing entities but it fails on a newly created entities. It seems that Oracle procedure does not see uncommitted data. I believed that the procedure shall share the same transaction and so it can actually see uncommitted data. I would prefer to have a single transaction, so if the procedure fails, Spring will rollback changes made both in Java and the procedure.

That should be possible, but we are missing parts of your code. Are any of the beans or methods you call annotated? And what about the Oracle procedure, does it use autonomous transaction? First though: check the SQL log. Do you see the insert? You may need to flush (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-flush) to get your changes into the database before calling the procedure.

There are many methods, but they all are private and don't have @transactional. entityManager.flush() is a workaround. Though I would be glad to understand, why it is needed.

Based on your answer to my comment above (flush is a workaround, why is it needed) I assume that it helped. You didn't share your code, but I assume that create does something like:
entityManager.persist(myNewEntity);

This creates the entity in memory and will create it in the database eventually, but there is nothing that forces JPA to execute the insert immediately. In general, JPA will wait until commit, manual flush or an automatic flush issued before a query (where JPA knows the flush is needed for correct results).
When you make your own database queries/updates outside of JPA, you first need to flush any pending changes. That is what flush is for.
Don't flush "just in case" as it hurts performance, but in this case you know that you have pending changes (you just created the entity) that the procedure needs to see. In that situation, flush is the way to go.

Yep, I realized that too. Entities saved by jparepository are waiting in L2 cache, so the flush is actually needed. If I turned on hibernate logging, I could spot it earlier.
